# How to disassemble this kind of tap?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink

I'm trying to disassemble my kitchen sink tap to change the washer. How do I do that with this model? I can't find any cap I can pop to show the screw underneath it.

[image]

Comment: Try unscrewing the handles, including their chrome shafts. They may act as set screws that, when removed, allow you to take apart the cross arms.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on that. My bath taps don't come off that way. I'd be more inclined to suspect the conical collars. Might need a 'jam jar opener' with a rubber strap to avoid damage. Assume anti-clockwise from the handle end [which means they'll feel like they turn opposite ways]. But before you do anything, double-check there isn't a simple locking screw out of sight round the back. Get a mirror to check. It might end up being both, handles come off frees up the end studs, then the cones, then you'll find the actual functional nut underneath.

Comment: Do you have any brand info? That might help someone (like you) find instructions for it.

Comment: @Tetsujin spot on! There is a locking screw opposite the handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the image [here](https://www.tapsandsinksonline.co.uk/product/white-ceramic-kitchen-tap-handle-3044r/) it looks like there are some set screws on the underside of the handle that should be able to be loosened with a small hex wrench.

[image: white handles showing set screws at the bottom of the handle]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!